# The tour page overrides my sidebar settings. Is this intentional?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, left-navigation

The tour page seems to override my stickiness setting for the left nav. Is this intentional or a bug?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some pages have the left nav collapsed by default. For example, the [Teams product page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams). Generally these pages are non-standard pages that aren't a part of the core Q&A experience.

Comment: thanks for the clarification! the food is not for me it is for the general public. understood